# Адаптация приложения под разные разрешения

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Как адаптировать *ios* приложение в *xcode* под все разрешения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Традиционно для этого используется `autolayout`. Его можно использовать программно, или в interface builder (что более наглядно).

Вкратце: вы должны установить набор правил (`constraints`) по которым элементы отрисовываются на экране. Например:

- фиксированная ширина и высота вью.
- фиксированное расстояние между вью
- привязка стороны вью к другому вью или краю экрана

и т.д.

Например [вот](http://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2) хороший туториал.